# Merge changes svn:mergeinfo but not files

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I want to merge revision `r1007` from the trunk into a pristine working copy of a `/branches/feature-branch`. The revision includes changes to 2 files that already exist in both trunk and branch.

I've tried with both tools TortoiseSVN and the command-line client and the result is always the same: the merge proceeds without errors but **no file contents get modified**. Only the `svn:mergeinfo` property gets (properly) updated to reflect `r1007`:

```
C:\>svn log -r1007 --verbose https://example.com.s:8443/svn/project/trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1007 | alvaro | 2011-02-01 17:44:37 +0100 (mar, 01 feb 2011) | 5 lines
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Servidor/web/importar/index.php
   M /trunk/Servidor/web/logica/importacion-ayuntamiento.php

Fix blah blah blah
------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\>svn merge https://example.com:8443/svn/project/trunk@1006 ^
          https://example.com:8443/svn/project/trunk@1007 ^
          C:\Project\feature-branch

C:\>svn status C:\Project\feature-branch
 M      C:\Project\feature-branch
```

(I've tried `svn merge -r1006:1007 https://example.com:8443/svn/project/trunk C:\Project\feature-branch` as well.)

The only involved directory that has a `svn:mergeinfo` property is `C:\Project\feature-branch` and I see nothing wrong in it:

```
/branches/branch-a:476-477,481,611,613-614,620-622,661-662,731,740-742,745-748,751,757,922,988
/branches/branch-b:482,489-497,499-589,598,603,610,625,627,636,638-640,646,648,657,668-672,682,684,690,700,715-718,720,722,725-730,762,764-767,770,773,778-779,782-789,803,805,807,826,834,836-837,839-859,869,875,882,900-905
/branches/branch-c:706,709,712,735,737-739,829,842-852,854,877,892,907-910,918
/trunk:1-942,980,986,991,995,1000,1007,1017-1021
```

The only change made by the merge is adding `,1007` to the `/trunk` line (it's not there before merging).

Do you have any idea of why the merge is neither copying my code changes nor failing?

**Update:** The source code itself can be merged just fine: I *can* create a patch an apply it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time but it turned out to be the typical effect of bad sleep and strained eyes.

I had committed `r1008` with a new feature on `/branches/feature-branch` that already contained those same changes (among others). Subversion is smart enough to realise that there is not need to port those new lines of code since there are already there in the target file. That's the correct behaviour.

(I guess that when I did manual patching in order to test I wasn't careful enough and interpreted the results wrong.)

How I made the same changes in two branches without merging is something I'll never know, but I *did* it: it's all in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but 1007 is already in the /trunk line:

> /trunk:1-942,980,986,991,995,1000,**1007**,1017-1021

Comment: Yep, it gets there *after* the merge. That's the only change to the working that gets done properly. It's not there *before* the merge because the r1007 hasn't been merged yet. But that's all that changes in the working copy: the properties of the root folder. No file contents get changed.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear what changes are expected to merge.